How to adjust the extent of imshow when using sharex
I plot two subplots with the parameter sharex, but the x axis of the two subplot is not align.
I want to get image like this:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 200, 20)
line = np.random.rand(20)
heatmap = np.random.rand(20)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
ax0, ax1 = fig.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[10,1], hspace=0))
ax0.plot(x, line)
ax0.plot(x, heatmap, color='purple')

extent = [x[0]-(x[1]-x[0])/2, x[-1]+(x[1]-x[0])/2, 0, 5]
ax1.imshow(heatmap[np.newaxis, :], cmap='Purples', extent=extent)
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax1.set_xticks(np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 5))


But when I replace the x above with other list I really want:
x = [5950.81666666667, 5952.27083333333, 5953.725, 5955.17916666667, 5956.63333333333, 5958.0875, 5959.54166666667, 5960.99583333333, 5962.45, 5963.90416666667, 5965.35833333333, 5966.8125, 5968.26666666667, 5969.72083333333, 5971.175, 5972.62916666667, 5974.08333333333, 5975.5375, 5976.99166666667, 5978.44583333333]
the image becomes the one below, where you can see the 1d heatmap in ax1 squashed together. How to solve this problem?


You need ax1.imshow(..., aspect='auto'). By default, the image will be created with a 1:1 aspect ratio.
